# How to pull timecode using AWK and ffmpeg

Tags: bash, awk, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use AWK to reference timecode in a file so I can burn into the picture later, using ffmpeg.

```
#!/bin/bash


set -x
for video in *.mxf
do
   filenoext="${video%.*}"
   mkdir "done_H264/$filenoext"
   mkdir "done_MXF/$filenoext"
   timecode=$( ffmpeg -i "$video" 2>&1 | awk -v video="$video" '$video ~ /^timecode/ {print $NF}' )
```

I've tried a manner of different inputs, but it never seems to be able to pull the timecode. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is really embarassing, but it was actually working after all. I think I had fixed it without realising it and kept on adding the filename after the script in the command line, not thinking to try it without. Sorry all, and thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for sharing your efforts in form of code, could you please do mention samples of input and expected output too in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for getting back to me so quickly. They're MXF files with embedded timecode. If I do the following:

`timecode=$( ffmpeg -i "$video" 2>&1 | awk '$1 ~ /^timecode/ {print $NF}' )`

It works, but I have to add the filename after the name of my script every time I run it, and I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Maybe you could share a Dropbox/Google Drive link to one of your files, and also say exactly what you expect to get created from processing it? Start by clicking `edit` under your question rather than scattering details through the comments area. Thank you.

Comment: What is "it" in the statement `but it never seems to be able...`? Is it `ffmpeg -i "$video" 2>&1`? Or does that give you the output you expected but then the pipe to awk doesn't or something else? When you say in a comment "this is the output" and then `++ awk -v 'video=190909 TTD Dailies Day 036_Marc_1_TEST.mxf' '$video ~ /^timecode/ {print $NF}' + timecode=` - are you saying something is printing that awk command line undesirably? Please [edit] your question to clarify what you're doing and where and how it's failing.

Comment: `'$video ~ /^timecode/ {print $NF}'` this will give you `awk: illegal field` unless "video" contains a number, which is possible but unlikely from your code if you files are not just numbers + .mxf

Comment: hmmm have you considered using ffprobe instead, and do the hideous output at either frame or packet level detail. can generic timestamps work or you need something specific for MXF (not too familiar with that format)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `ffprobe` to get the timecode:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=timecode -of csv=p=0 input.mxf
```

Result (drop-frame example):

```
01:02:03;04
```

The `ffmpeg` output is not meant for machine reading and you can avoid `awk`, so using `ffprobe` instead is better.